# Create json with a query on mongodb by python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, api

create api with python and use this code

```
def findusers():
    x = mycollection_users.find()
    return x

@app.route('/api/users', methods=['GET'])
def users():
    db = findusers()
    js = jsonpickle.encode(db)
    return Response(response=js, status=200, mimetype="application/json")
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=4000)
```

then json is:

```
{
    "py/iterator": [
        {
            "City": "Us",
            "Phone": "02",
            "_id": 1,
            "name": "Tom"
        },
        {
            "City": "EN",
            "Phone": "11",
            "_id": 2,
            "name": "Jack"
        },
    ],
    "py/object": "pymongo.cursor.Cursor"
}
```

How to delete "py/iterator": and "py/object": `pymongo.cursor.Cursor` ?
i want this format: `[{},{}]`

Answer (score 0):

How does this look? If you don't want those two keys in the dictionary, you can simply access the portion you do care about.

```
>>> a = {
...     "py/iterator": [
...         {
...             "City": "Us",
...             "Phone": "02",
...             "_id": 1,
...             "name": "Tom"
...         },
...         {
...             "City": "EN",
...             "Phone": "11",
...             "_id": 2,
...             "name": "Jack"
...         },
...     ],
...     "py/object": "pymongo.cursor.Cursor"
... }
...
>>> b = a['py/iterator']
>>> print(b)
[{'City': 'Us', '_id': 1, 'name': 'Tom', 'Phone': '02'}, {'City': 'EN', '_id': 2, 'name': 'Jack', 'Phone': '11'}]
```

Comment: because i use the jason in api and client side will read it thus i want to know why create those!

Comment: I believe those keys are being inserted because of the JSON pickler. Could you potentially send the raw dict?

Comment: i checked my db but i haven't those (my db is mongodb)

Comment: please try the following:
return Response(response=db, status=200, mimetype="application/json")

Comment: return one row while it has't any data.

Comment: What about the following?
return Response(response=db.__dict__, status=200, mimetype="application/json")

Comment: '_Cursor__id_Cursor__exhaust_Cursor__exhaust_mgr_Cursor__killed_Cursor__session_Cursor__explicit_session_Cursor__collection_Cursor__spec_Cursor__projection_Cursor__skip_Cursor__limit_Curso' and continue